# Deduplication optimization

Tags: c, list, algorithm, c89

The problem is as follows. I want a function that, given a list and a max number of occurrences "x", deletes all elements of the list that appear more than x times or x times.

I found a pretty straightforward solution, which is to check for each of the elements. This said, to repeat the find and delete functions many times seems computationally-wise not optimal to me.

I was wondering whether you could provide a better algorithm (i excluded allocating memory for a matrix from the min to the max... just too much for the task... say you have few very big numbers and your memory won't do it.)

My code follows.

```c
typedef struct n_s
{
    int val;
    struct n_s *next;
}
n_t;

// deletes all elements equal to del in list with head h
n_t * delete(n_t *h, int del);
// returns the first occurrence of find in list with head h, otherwise gives NULL
n_t * find(n_t *h, int find);

n_t *
delFromList(n_t *h, int x)
{
    int val;
    n_t *el, *posInter;

    // empty list case
    if (h == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // first element
    val=h->val;
    if ( (posInter = find(h -> next,val)) 
        && (find(posInter -> next, val)))
        h = delete(h, val);

    // loop from second element
    el = h;
    while (el -> next)
    {
        val = el -> next -> val;
        // check whether you want to delete the next one, 
        // and then if you do so, check again on the "new" next one
        if ((posInter = find(el -> next -> next, val))                   
            && (find(posInter -> next, val)))
            el -> next = delete(el -> next, val);
        // in case you did not delete the nexy node, you can move on
        else 
            el = el -> next;

    }

    return h;
}
```

I know that the el->next->next may look confusing, but I find it less intuitive to use variables such as "next", "past"... so, sorry for your headache.

Comment: You should specify context for this. If it is for a class assignment, there are typically either constraints that must be obeyed or there is context for the lesson being learned that guides what solutions should be used. If it is a real world problem, then it should be questioned why you are using a linked list for this and what alternative or additional data structures we can consider.

Comment: "you have few very big numbers and your memory won't do it": what ?

Comment: Is modifying the definition of the list an option? If yes you could have a third field that keeps track of the times the value "appears" on the list. That would mean that you would have to change your whole program completely though.

Comment: Not a great idea to declare an array of 100000 numbers when in your list you have 0, 1, 2 and 99999 @YvesDaoust. Probably i should have used an example

Comment: As a matter of logical necessity, when examining an item in the list and deciding whether to keep it or delete it, you need to know whether it is a duplicate or not. Given only a linked list, the only way to do that is to search through the list. And thus the operation time is O(n) per element, and there are n elements so it is O(n^2). However, we can construct additional data, such as reading the list and preparing a sorted copy (O(n log n)) and then can go through the list using lookups in the sorted copy O(log n) to determine whether each element is a duplicate (O(n log n) total).

Comment: @YvesDaoust: The range of the data values is so large that they do not have sufficient memory for an array indexed by data value.

Comment: "Not a great idea...": indeed, nobody would even think of that. (You did not even say that your keys are naturals.)

Comment: It is a class assignment @EricPostpischil but i do not have particular constraint, but not to use exotic libraries. I was just wondering whether i could simplfy or improve computationally the solution.

Comment: What is the assignment? To get the deduplication job done or to optimize the compute time of the deduplication job?

Comment: @YvesDaous why is it best to use curr and succ? I do not really understand the practice. you have to manage more variable... to me that only makes the code more confusing and error-prone

Comment: The job is to get it done. But out of curiosity, i was trying to optimize it too... I do not code for the class, but to improve my skills.

Comment: Well, as far as i can see it doesn't really have any problem with integer-managing @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option for an algorithm with improved performance is:

- Define a data structure `D` with two members, one for the value of a list element and one to count the number of times it appears.
- Initialize an empty balanced tree ordered by value.
- Iterate through the list. For each item in the list, look it up in the tree. If it is not present, insert a `D` structure into that tree with its value member copied from the list element and its count set to one. If it is present in the tree, increments its count. If its count equals or exceeds the threshold, remove it from the list.

Lookups and insertions in a balanced tree are O(log n). A linked list of n items uses n of them, and deletions from a linked list are O(1). So the total time is O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

Use a counting map to count the number of times each element appears. The keys are the elements, and the values are the counts.

Then, go through your array a second time, deleting anything which meets your threshold.

O(n) time, O(n) extra space.

Comment: A map either requires more than O(n) time (more than O(1) per element for n elements) or O(r) space, where r is the range of the elements, not the number of them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Is that in reference to the possibility of the hashing function producing a large number of collisions relative to the number of distinct inputs?

Comment: @EricPostpischil In any case, I don't see why the range of elements would matter. A map that has two elements very far amount doesn't need to be massive.

Comment: If you do not have O(r) storage for a map, there may be collisions, and you need to manage them somehow, and that cannot be done in O(1) time per collision.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have to stand by my answer. The likelihood of collisions is affected by the number of unique elements being hashed and the space used by the map, but not by the range of elements being hashed. E.g., say we have two sets of things to hash. Set 'A' has {1, 10^100} and set 'B' has all integers 1 through 100. For the same size map, B is much likelier to have collisions than A.

Comment: You could claim your algorithm has good performance in some subset of cases. But the “O” notation means the limit applies to all cases. Claiming the algorithm uses O(n) time with O(n) space is incorrect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Wikipedia says O(n) space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table, CLRS Intro to Algorithms says O(n) space (2nd ed, ch 11.2 "Hash tables").

Comment: Yes, a hash is O(n) space. It is not O(n) time, as this answer incorrectly says. As my comment says, a map either requires more than O(n) time or requires O(r) space. Stating a map solution is both O(n) time and O(n) space is incorrect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Would you be satisfied if I added the word 'expected' -- expected O(n) time since the hash operations are all expected O(1) time? I still don't know where you're getting O(r) from -- the range is irrelevant.